# how to add i18n attribute to custom attribute with object type in angular

Tags: angular, internationalization, angular-i18n

I have a component that takes a parameter of type object(`errorMessage`). One of the property(`maximumDate`) of that object accepts a static text. I recently started internationalizing the application and not sure how to add `i18n` attribute for such cases. Did anyone else face a similar situation? any help is appreciated.

```
<mycomp label="Date of Birth" [errorMessage]="{maximumDate: 'Date of birth can not be future date.'}">
</mycomp>
```

Comment: You can define the string in your (typescript) component and use the `$localize`-function there